# JS - removeEventListener not removing the event

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

Removing the event does not actually remove it. My guess is it's because of the **.bind**, it is giving it a different function address when trying to remove the function compared to when adding the function. However, I can not figure out how to give the removeEventListener function the proper address.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".cell").forEach(function(cell, index){
    cell.style.filter = "blur(4px)";
    // Adding event
    cell.addEventListener("transitionend", cellFadeIn.bind(null, cell, index));
});
                                        
function cellFadeIn(cell, index){
    if (index == 1){
        document.getElementById("heading-wrap").style.transform = "rotate3d(1,0,0,0deg)"; 
    }
    cell.style.transition = ".75s";
    cell.style.filter = "blur(20px) saturate(110%)";
    // Removing event
    cell.removeEventListener("transitionend", cellFadeIn);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution is just add a property to the `cell` to store the index and use `this` in handler as you normally would when not using `bind()`

```
document.querySelectorAll(".cell").forEach(function(cell, index){
    // add index to element itself
    cell.idx = index;

    cell.style.filter = "blur(4px)";
    // Adding event
    cell.addEventListener("transitionend", cellFadeIn);
});
                                        
function cellFadeIn(evt){
    if (this.idx == 1){
      // idx set above in forEach
        document.getElementById("heading-wrap").style.transform = "rotate3d(1,0,0,0deg)"; 
    }
    this.style.transition = ".75s";
    this.style.filter = "blur(20px) saturate(110%)";
    // Removing event
    this.removeEventListener("transitionend", cellFadeIn);
}
```

Comment: Another way is use a wrapper function `addCellListener(cell, index)` and declare `function cellFadeIn()` inside that function so a new handler function is created for every element. Then `index` will be inside the `addCellListener` closure

Answer (score 0):

bind() creates a new and different function. You can assign the binded function to a temporary variable and then use that with removeEventListener().

```js
let bindedCellFadeIn;

document.querySelectorAll(".cell").forEach(function(cell, index){
    cell.style.filter = "blur(4px)";
    // Adding event
    cell.addEventListener("transitionend", bindedCellFadeIn = cellFadeIn.bind(null, cell, index));
});
                                        
function cellFadeIn(cell, index){
    if (index == 1){
        document.getElementById("heading-wrap").style.transform = "rotate3d(1,0,0,0deg)"; 
    }
    cell.style.transition = ".75s";
    cell.style.filter = "blur(20px) saturate(110%)";
    // Removing event
    cell.removeEventListener("transitionend", bindedCellFadeIn);
    bindedCellFadeIn = undefined;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately, I already tried that and it does not work. I pasted your code just to be safe and confirmed it does not work.

Comment: This overwrites `bindedCellFadeIn` every iteration of the loop so would only work on the last one